# Rails: Wicked couldn't find <object> withoun an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to implement a wizard with `wicked` into my rails application.

The redirection after save is working, but when I try to update my `@product` through my `general.html.erb` view, I get the following error `Couldn't find Product without an ID`

I have two seperate controllers for `Prodouct`.

My routes:

`resources :products`

`resources :product_steps`

Products Controller

```
  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(product_params)
    if @product.save
      redirect_to product_step_path(product_id: @product.id, id: :general)
      # redirect_to is working
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

ProductSteps Controller

```
class ProductStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :update]
  steps :general, :categories, :pricing, :pictures

  def show
    # The first show action for :general is working
    # The second show action for :categories isn't working
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @product.attributes = params[:product_id]
    render_wizard @product
  end

private
  def set_product
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:product_id])
  end
end
```

My view for `:general`

```
<%= form_for @product, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.submit "Continue", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should be

```
@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:product][:id])
```